# When a path is not specified, where are files saved by default in Pharo?

Tags: file, save, smalltalk, pharo

I'm currently learning Pharo through the [Pharo MOOC](https://mooc.pharo.org/), and in the lecture "3.8 Stream Overview", we are presented the following example of a stream operation used to create files:

```
| stream |
stream := 'hello.txt' asFileReference writeStream.
stream nextPutAll: 'Hello Pharo!'.
stream close.
```

I executed this code snippet in playground, then I looked the folder where I installed Pharo, under ~/src/pharolauncher in Ubuntu 20.04, to check if the file was created, but it was nowhere in the folder or its subfolders.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a relative path and would like to convert it to absolute, right?

OK. The key part of your code is

```
'hello.txt' asFileReference
```

If you inspect this object you will see its class is, not surprisingly, `FileReference`. Browse the class. Find some selector containing the word `'absolute'` or `'Absolute'`. The one that looks promising is `#absolutePath`. Give it a try.

Comment: Awesome answer! You were faster than me by one minute or so 

Comment: @Uko My apologies. Next time I will control myself. I promise!

Comment: Executing 'hello.txt' asFileReference absolutePath and inspecting the results, I got a object with contents "Path / 'home' / 'user' / 'Pharo' / 'images' / 'Pharo Mooc' / 'hello.txt'". Problem solved. Thank you! So there was another folder created under my home folder. I thought everything was saved under the original install folder, and so I did not pay attention to it.

Comment: @LeandroCaniglia no need to apologise. I find it to be a fun competition. Sometimes I post first, sometimes you do. Sometimes we provide different answers, sometimes we thing in the same way. In the end the person who asked the question wins :)